# Makefile is always not up to date even without any changes

Tags: makefile

I have a directory with two folders, `src` and `bin` with the makefile at root directory. This makefile keeps compiling (not up to date) even without changes. Am I missing something with this makefile?

```
all:
    make a b

a: ./src/a.cpp
    g++ -o ./bin/a ./src/a.cpp

b: ./src/b.cpp
    g++ -o ./bin/b ./src/b.cpp
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your rules claim to create the files `a` and `b`, but they don't: They create `bin/a` and `bin/b`.

So when `make` checks your rules, it always finds that `a` and `b` don't exist and tries to create them by executing their associated commands.

Possible fix:

```
.PHONY: all

all: bin/a bin/b

bin/a: src/a.cpp
    g++ -o bin/a src/a.cpp

bin/b: src/b.cpp
    g++ -o bin/b src/b.cpp
```

On `.PHONY`: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html#Phony-Targets

Comment: May I know what .PHONY is?
I've tried the code but now I get `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.`