# Make - what files do I need to state as prerequisites for a target with multiple #include statements?

Tags: makefile

Assuming I have this example.h:

```
// example.h
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"
#include "d.h"
#include "e.h"
```

And example.c:

```
// example.c
#include "example.h"
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"
#include "d.h"
#include "e.h"
```

Should my Makefile look like this? :

```
example.o : example.h example.c
    gcc -c example.c -o example.o
```

Or should it look like this? :

```
example.o : example.h example.c a.h b.h c.h d.h e.h
    gcc -c example.c -o example.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It should look like your second version:

```
example.o : example.h example.c a.h b.h c.h d.h e.h
    gcc -c example.c -o example.o
```

2) There is no reason for the same `#include` statement to appear in both `example.h` and `example.c`, and redundant `#include` statements are kruft and ought to be removed. For safety, put them in `example.h`; for efficiency, put them in `example.c` when you can. (I won't go into the details of when you can here, but the compiler will tell you when you get it wrong.)

3) If you don't want to maintain that list of headers in the makefile, gcc and Make can take care of it for you. Here's an example, but this is [an advanced technique](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/), so I advise you not to use it until you understand how it works:

```
example.o : example.c
    gcc -MMD -c example.c -o example.o

-include *.d
```

Comment: @J.Doe: I see a few rough spots. I suspect it won't rebuild files at the right times.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @J.Doe: Ideally Make will rebuild files when they ought to be rebuilt, and not rebuild them when there's no reason to; I think your makefile will rebuild every object file every time.

Comment: @J.Doe: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32781806/makefile-is-always-not-up-to-date-even-without-any-changes).